# Identifying if there are unwanted characters in a string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the a series of `UITextFields` that enable the user to enter text. I need to check the text for characters that are not allowed. I can have a series of lines such as:

```
noOfBadChars = [[textBox1.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"] count];
noOfBadChars = noOfBadChars + [[textBox2.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"*"] count];
if (noOfBadChars>1)
{
    ….
}
```

but is there a simple way of checking this as I don't want to have to check for every bad char separately, or perhaps there is a way of limiting the entry to just A to Z chars?

Comment: not sure whether there's style guide info on this.  the better behavior might be to catch the forbidden characters during input (shouldChangeCharactersInRange), don't insert them and give a little alert reminding user of the valid chars.  @nhgrif answer is perfectly good in this context, too.  simpler, because you're just testing if the input is in the char set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSCharacterSet *charsToRemove = [NSCharacterSet
    characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"example"];
```

Where `example` is replace with the characters you want to remove.

```
NSString *finalString = [[originalString 
    componentsSeperatedByCharactersInCharacterSet: charsToRemove]
    componentsJoinedByString: @""];
```

This will replace the entered text with a text that has all the characters removed.

Otherwise, if you just want to check and see whether it contained a bad character, you can do:

```
NSArray *temp = [originalString componentsSeperatedByCharactersInCharacterSet:
    charsToRemove];
if ([temp count] > 1) {
    // do stuff
}
```

---

`NSCharacterSet` has a lot of constant character sets for common needs.

```
NSCharacterSet *charsToKeep = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
```

That will make `charsToKeep` a character set including only letters.  Now you can use `invertedSet` to get the inverse.

```
NSCharacterSet *charsToRemove = [charsToKeep 
    invertedSet];
```

`charsToRemove` will now be a character set that includes every character that's not in the `letterCharacterSet`.

You can do this all in one line as such:

```
NSCharacterSet *charsToRemove = [[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] 
    invertedSet];
```

---

If you want letters AND numbers, use `alphanumericCharacterSet` instead of `letterCharacterSet`.

The [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nscharacterset_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a list of all the character sets.

Comment: That is a neat answer but still requires me to consider ever non A-Z character there is. Is there no way of limiting entry to A-Z only?

Comment: You only want to allow letters?

Comment: Yes - possibly numbers too but nothing else

Comment: Thank you so much and it looks utterly perfect. But when I enter     NSArray *temp = [textbox1.text componentsSeperatedByCharactersInCharacterSet:charsToRemove]; it doesn't like the textbox1.text bit …. a syntax thing maybe?

Comment: Try saving `textbox1.text` to an `NSString` first.

Comment: An excellent help thanks - you need to change >1 to >0 though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

componentsSeparatedBy methods will potentially create a whole bunch of objects as a side-effect. If you don't need the substrings, it would be much more efficient to use a method like

rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:range.

You could write a loop that would step through the string, finding each character from the set of unwanted characters.